# "See full review" link in the review text for video.rates does not show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Recently I used rottentomatoes facebook app to review movies. When I review a movie, rottent tomatoes creates the following story.

[image: Rotten Tomatoes Story Screenshot]

If you look closely there is a **"see full review"** link at the end of the review text. This link is created by facebook (I think so because it has fb ref parameters at the end) and refers to the actual review on the site.

Now the problem is I have an app that uses "video.movie" type with "video.rates" action. But when I create review stories with my app, the "see full review" link does not appear

[image: Rinema review story screenshot]

Is there any flag or property that needs to be set in order to get "see full review" link.

"video.rates" - [reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/video.rates) & [guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/video.rates/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out: When generating the story if you use `review_text` property of `video.rates` action, then facebook will not generate *see full review* link.

So if you want full review link, dont use the review_text property. Simple!